# Fetch as Google says my page is "Temporary Unreachable"

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, crawl-errors, fetch-as-google

When looking into it in WebmasterTools, I saw that there is a "Fetch as Google - Temporarily Unreachable Issue". It is for an image, and font.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [Google's help document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) says about it:

> #### Temporarily unreachable
>
> 1. Fetch as Google can’t currently fetch your URL because the server took too long to reply.
>
> OR
>
> 2. Fetch as Google cancelled your fetch because too many consecutive requests were made to the server for different URLs.
>
> Note the URL is not unreachable for all of Google-- it is just unreachable for the Fetch as Google simulation tool.

Unless your server is slow for your users, I wouldn't worry about it. You can try fetching as Google again and it may not have the error the next time.   It sounds like this error doesn't even mean that the Googlebot crawler will have problems accessing your website.